# how to change persistent object to transient object in arraylist hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Actually I am creating one `arraylist` of transient object . Now I am passing this `arraylist` to `BatchInsert` method since I am i using hibernate batch .

Now if i pass my `arraylist` with transient objects to `batchInsert` method and call session.save method , all transient object will convert to persistent objects.
And now this `arraylist` will contain persistent object .

i ) Now problem is that if any exception occur in `batchInsert` method and then I want to save all records indivisually , so i want my arralylist with  transient object only. But problem is that i am not able to reproduce arraylist with transient object .

ii) Problem is that , initially this arraylist can contain transient or persistent object since i have to  insert or  update both .   After batch processing arraylist will contain only persistent object only . Now how i will identify in arraylist what i have to insert or update ?

Comment: [Session.evict()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict(java.lang.Object))

Comment: I don't see any problem defining that array list global and use it after your batch execution for individual execution if needed.

Comment: i) After batch processing i am using sesion.clear already and that not solving my problem . ii) Problem is that , initially this arraylist can contain transient or persistent object  both since i have to  insert or  update both . After batch processing arraylist will contain only persistent object only . Now how i will identify in arraylist what i have to insert or update ?